# Sqlite Returned error =1 msg= near "CREATE TABLE" syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

what is the problem in my code every time i run the code i got the error and couldn't find the error

```
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE_TABLE " +  DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_MNAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CHECKEDM + " TEXT NOT NULL, ");

    }
```

Comment: no underscore in create_table

Answer (score 2):

It should be create space Table as below. You have it as "create_table" you have to remove the '_' symbol between create and table.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +  DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_MNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CHECKEDM + " TEXT NOT NULL);")
```

A good read about the command [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp)

Comment: The syntax is also wrong at the end, finishes with a comma and not a close bracket, so that'll throw another error.

Comment: Thats right!! Corrected that

Comment: Not quite, should have been after `TEXT NOT NULL` to close the bracket after the table name. Edited it to fix it now.

Comment: Yup..thats embarrasing mistake :)

Comment: @P.shahin if it worked can you mark it answered

Answer (score 2):

You should remove *_* from *CREATE TABLE* and give *White Space*. Also at last you missing closing brackets.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " +  DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_MNAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CHECKEDM + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }
```

Comment: It works thank u :)

Comment: @P.shahin if any of these answers have helped you, make sure to accept the one that's helped you most by clicking the ✔ icon on the left, under the score.

Answer (score 0):

You should change CREATE_TABLE to Create Table, remove unnecessary comma and close parenthesis